# Fetch images path in remote server folders

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch images path from remote server to Android codes . How can I access in doInbackground I am making a static URL ( http:xyz.com/smb/webapps/ "dynamic folder"/ "Dynamic folder"/image.jpg .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please try to post what you have done so far. It is very unclear what you are asking now, Otherwise your question will be deleted soon after

Comment: Can you post code what you have tried as your question is not clear.